# Why is my color being overridden using css-modules?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules

I am trying to understand why my color is being overridden in my `CSS` when I am using `css-modules`. Here is my `jsx`:

```
let tabLink = className({
    [s.selected]: selectTab
});

<li className={s.tabs}>
    <a className={tabLink}>{tab.translation}</a>
</li>
```

And here is the `CSS`:

```
.tabs {
    color: #454545;
}
.tabs li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.tabs li a {
    color: #454545;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.selected {
    background: url('../../images/header_nav_on.gif') top left repeat-x;
    color: white;
}
```

So when `selectTab` is true, then `s.selected` is applied to the element. In that case, `color` is `white`, but it is not applied to the element.  the `color` that is defined in `.tab li a` is overriding it.  I am having to add `!important` to `white` to make it be the `color`.  What am I not understanding about `css` or `css-modules`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.tabs li a` is more specific than `.selected`. If you want `.selected` to overwrite the default, try `.tabs .selected {
    background: url('../../images/header_nav_on.gif') top left repeat-x;
    color: white;
}`.

You can use the following formula to calculate specificity: +100 for id, +10 for class, +1 for tag.

That makes `.tabs li a` worth 12 (class(10) + tag(1) + tag(1)) VS `.selected`, which is only 10. If you make it `.tabs .selected` instead, it will be worth 20 (class(10) + class(10)) and will put it above the default value.